# try statement using GoogleMaps 1.0.2

Tags: python, google-maps

I'm using the python module googlemaps 1.0.2 and I cannot use a try statement in the instance that the user inputs an unknown address.

The error message that I get looks like this:

```
GoogleMapsError: Error 602: G_GEO_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS
```

My method looks like this, (without my API key):

```
from googlemaps import GoogleMaps
def get_distance(address, destination):
    try:
        gmaps = GoogleMaps(api_key)
        directions = gmaps.directions(address,destination)
        distance = directions['Directions']['Distance']['meters']/1600.0
        return distance
    except ???:
```

I have tried:

```
except GoogleMapsError:
except 'GoogleMapsError: Error 602: G_GEO_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS'
```

thanks

Comment: `from googlemaps import GoogleMaps, GoogleMapsError` ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably haven't imported the googlemaps.GoogleMapsError exception.

```
from googlemaps import GoogleMaps, GoogleMapsError

def get_distance(address, destination):
    try:
        gmaps = GoogleMaps(api_key)
        directions = gmaps.directions(address,destination)
        distance = directions['Directions']['Distance']['meters']/1600.0
        return distance
    except GoogleMapsError:
        pass
```